# Rails application is not running on default 80 port. But runs on every port other than 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, centos, passenger

I have an issue with apache vhost. I am running `rails 2.0.2` app on `centos6`. The app is running on **Webrick server**. Now I have set the virtual host in apache but issue is that the application is not working on **port 80**. But it is running on every other port than 80.

What should be the reason?

Following is the code in my `app.conf` file-

> /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/app.conf

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>

 DocumentRoot /var/www/app/public
 ServerName www.domainname.com
 ServerAlias domainname.com

 ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app/error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app/access.log common

 <Directory /var/www/app/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have included this `app.conf` file to my `httpd.conf` file by following statement.

```
Include sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Please suggest if I am missing something in both **app.conf** and **httpd.conf** files. Its very urgent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any other servers listening on port 80?

Comment: `netstat -tlnp | grep 80` returns a result?

Comment: You probalby have an other application running on port 80. You can use `netstat -lnptu` to check the used ports

Comment: check whether you have read and write permissions for the log folders and make sure you started the apache server once you changed the configurations

Comment: tcp        0      0 :::8880                     :::*                        LISTEN      20588/sw-cp-serverd

Comment: can you run `netcat -l -p 80` as root? if not, then another application is starting; if you can run this, then the port is free to use, and you have a problem somewhere else, in this case, check the apache logfiles.

Comment: Getting -bash: netcat: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out which process is running on port 80.

Use -

```
netstat -ant
```

If you want to open a single port use:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Also you can take help about [which process is lisening port 80](http://www.xerxesb.com/2009/finding-out-whats-process-is-listening-on-port-80/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but My issue is apache is starting on 80 port but it do not launch the apllication on port 80. If I change the apache port to any other number eg 8080, 8090, 800, 30000 then applications launches on that port successfully.

Comment: then this is because some other process is using your port 80. If you are on ubuntu then it is easy to determine that which process is using port 80 by the command- `lsof -i|grep 80`

Comment: Hey! The issue has been resolved. There already a Virtual Host had been created with different Document Root by the web hosting company. I moved my app directory to that path and application started. Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Accept or upvote any answer that you found useful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are running `apache` and `webrick` at the same time, they cannot *both* listen on port 80.

Comment: No corrently webrick is not running.

Comment: I have installed passenger as well. And added the passenger.conf to the path /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running an other application on port 80, this might actually be the WebRick you are using to test the application.

Use `netstat -lnptu` to check which ports are used, it might show that it is used by webrick, or something else.

You also have to start `apache` as `root`, as ports below 1024 can only be opened with `root` access. (you can change this behaviour in centos, refer to: https://serverfault.com/questions/84360/regular-user-using-ports-below-1024 )

Comment: root access may indeed be the issue in my opinion, +1 for this answer.